Creating a configuration wizard for a C# Windows Form Application
I am creating a C# Windows Form Application which will be deployed to different areas. This application executes PowerShell Script in host computers; however, each script is stored in different areas. I want to create a configuration wizard so when the user first opens the application, they set up by entering location of the scripts and any other variable which the application will use for subsequent uses.
I tried creating another C# Windows Form Application that has the necessary prompts. But I do not how to connect it, so the information received in one is send to the other and that it opens only one time and not subsequent times.

You could add your configuration parameters to an appsettings file and give users an interface to edit them.

One can store this information in a configuration file as someone else mentioned., or in the registry. You could even use a hybrid approach, where the location of the configuration file is stored in the registry. Any entries to the registry should be made by the application installer, although an application may provide an interface to modify this value. If the registry information only applies to a particular user, store it in HKCU, otherwise, HKLM. Also see Environment.SpecialFolder Enum
